# I have a very large feature class I would like to symbolize for a basemap, but having issues with performance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography

Im using ArcMap 10.5 to make an ArcReader map viewer for my office. For the basemap, im using data sourced from an Open Street Map data extract. I would like to display buildings polygons as just uniform grey polygons on my basemap. My map region is very large and the buildings featureclass contains almost 10 million polygons.  I do not need these features to be labeled and there doesn't really need to be any data associated with them either since they are purely being used for reference on the basemap. The features are set to not turn on until 5k scale, meaning once turned on, there are maximum 50 or so features on the screen at once. Yet, it is still painfully slow. So far I have tried to merge all features into one multi-part feature, but this actually decreased performance, and I have also tried the Polygon to Raster tool, but my output was blank (I believe this was because the feature class' extent is roughly 8 states and was too large to produce the Raster file, however I am not very experienced with creating or using rasters at all.)

Comment: Have you tried some kind of caching? (I dont know what is possible in ArcReader)

Comment: One massive polygon wouldn't work, but intersecting the footprints with a fishnet, then dissolving on tile ID would. Just be sure to use the same color for edges as for fill.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the Open Street map basemap that is slowing you down rather than the polygon shapefile? Have you tried turning of the basemap and see if the performance is faster?